# Jquery methods not working

Tags: jquery

i downloaded jQuery v3.1.1 (uncompressed) from the jquery.com site and added the script for including it in the html and wrote an alert method to check if its working. turns out nothing is happening when i use the document.ready or onload() functions, jquery just isn't working....
My code is....

```
<srcipt type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></srcipt>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        alert("Hello, world");
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked thet script loaded corectly, any 404 etc?

Comment: Output of the Browser Console would be good, too!

Comment: `<script></script>` not `<srcipt></srcipt>`

Comment: And there's no reason to include `type` if the content is JavaScript. JavaScript is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i got an solution to my problem after a little modifications, turns out the downloaded copy of jQuery 3.1.1 which was uncompressed for developers had an error that keeps it from working, when i inserted a link using the CDN (online) it worked,just replace the static file in the script with the script pointing to the file in the CDN i.e.Change 
`<srcipt type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></srcipt>`

To

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also click the link, copy the code on the webpage and replace the one in your static file with it and the static file should work once again without a problem, did that and its okay now, alert displaying with both CDN and static/offline jQuery